# Where should "kind of" be placed?

Tags: word-in-context

Is it

> It is a disruptive kind of move.

or

> It is a kind of disruptive move.

Comment: It depends upon what you want to express. _It is a disruptive kind of move_ means that it is a move that can be classified as disuptive. _It is a kind of disruptive move_ means something rather different: that the move is to some degree, and not completely, disruptive. In the second instance, the phrase _kind of_ is used idiomatically as an adverb meaning _to a moderate degree._

Comment: In the second, the word _kind_ is not a noun meaning [_character or nature._](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/kind) as it is in the first. Instead, it is part of the idiomatic modifier [_kind of_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kind_of) meaning _in some way._ (Sometimes this is pronounced as _kinda_ in NAmE.)

Comment: But it sounds like both of them give us the same meaning. If I want to describe a move as close to being disruptive, I could choose either expression, correct?

Comment: The meanings are different. The first describes what sort of a move it is: disruptive. The second tells us that it is disruptive, but not very much so. If I say "The weather is of a warm kind," I mean only that the weather is warm, with no hint of _how_ warm it is. If I say: "The weather is _kind of_ warm," I mean that it is not very warm. The dictionary links I provided make the distinction clear. "Kind of" as an idiomatic modifier means _somewhat,_ or _slightly;_ _not completely._

Comment: To express "close to disruptive," use your second model.

Comment: If you want to use it in a colloquial way, meaning 'somewhat',  you should really say say "It's kind of a disruptive move".  https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=%22kind+of+a%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=wgHdV5PFMcT4aoyKr9gM

Answer (score 3):

There are actually three places where kind of could go:

> It is a disruptive kind of move

The move is of a disruptive type.

> It is kind of a disruptive move

The move is quite disruptive. This use of kind of is quite colloquial.

> It is a kind of disruptive move

This is ambiguous and could mean the same as either of the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Being an adverb of degree, [*kind of*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kind%20of) (informal for *somewhat, rather, to some extent, to a moderate degree*, etc.) is used to give information about the extent or degree of something. This is how it is used in your second sentence, where *kind of* modifies the adjective  *disruptive*.  If this is what you wanted to express, then you've done it.

If your intention was to classify the move as disruptive (see P.E.Dant's comment), then it's been done in the first sentence.